# One of the two text fields must be filled in

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

There are currently two text fields called reg_12 / reg_13 in the form.

The double reg_12 or reg_13 fields must be filled in.

I did it like below
It only checks when neither reg_12 nor reg_13 has a value.
When both text fields are filled in, the submission is complete.

```
        if (reg_12.value.length === 0 && reg_13.value.length === 0) {
            alert("One of the two must be entered.");
            return false;
        }
```

As the question title says,
There should be only one reg_12 and reg_13 text field value.

have both reg_12 and reg_13 text fields, or
How can I make it stop when both the reg_12 and reg_13 text fields are missing?

Comment: you current check is ok,it only `return false` when both reg_12 and reg_13 are empty

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is the *exclusive OR* operator `XOR`, which can be represented with this conditional matrix:

```
reg_12  reg_13  result

true    true    false
false   false   false
true    false   true
false   true    true
```

...where `true` means that it's filled and `false` that it´s empty. You can observe that when reg_12 state and reg_13 state are equal, the result is `false`.

This conditional can be easily achieved in JS with this sentence:

```js
if (Boolean(reg_12.value.length) === Boolean(reg_13.value.length)) {
   alert("One of the two must be entered.");
   return false;
}
```

That can be also written as:

```js
if (!reg_12.value.length === !reg_13.value.length) {
   alert("One of the two must be entered.");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it, you have the following conditions/requirements:

1. If reg_12 and reg_13 are both empty, an error must be shown
2. If reg_12 and reg_13 are both filled, an error must be shown
3. If reg_12 is filled and reg_13 is empty, the form is OK
4. If reg_12 is empty and reg_13 is filled, the form is OK

With that in mind, you'll probably do best to break this into a few different conditions and use some nice, semantically named variables in order to meet these requirements.  While you probably *could* do it in a more succinct manner, I suspect readability would suffer and maintenance might become difficult.  I'd suggest something like this:

```js
function checkForm(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const reg12 = document.querySelector('#reg_12');
  const reg13 = document.querySelector('#reg_13');

  const reg12IsFilled = reg12.value.length > 0;
  const reg13IsFilled = reg13.value.length > 0;

  const bothAreFilled = reg12IsFilled && reg13IsFilled;
  const neitherAreFilled = !reg12IsFilled && !reg13IsFilled;

  if (neitherAreFilled) {
    console.log('one of these needs to be filled');
  } else if (bothAreFilled) {
    console.log('only on of these can be filled');
  } else {
    console.log('everything looks good here!');
  }
}

document.querySelector('#checkForm').addEventListener('click', checkForm);
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reg_12">reg 12</label>
    <input id="reg_12" name="reg_12" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reg_12">reg 13</label>
    <input id="reg_13" name="reg_13" />
  </div>

  <button id="checkForm" >Check Form</button>
</form>
```

You can simplify and remove some of the abstractions, but the logic is sound.